# Appending datetime rows and forward filling data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Beginner panda/python user. 
I am using 24 hour data in pandas dataframe, however there is often no data for the last few minutes of the day.

I simply need to append rows onto each file until the last Timestamp reaches 23.59, and forward fill those last few minutes with data. So this:

```
    19-12-2016 00:00    2   0.003232323
    ...
    19-12-2016 23:53    2   0.002822919
    19-12-2016 23:54    4   0.002822919
    19-12-2016 23:55    1   0.002822919
```

becomes:

```
    19-12-2016 00:00    2   0.003232323
    ...
    19-12-2016 23:53    2   0.002822919
    19-12-2016 23:54    4   0.002822919
    19-12-2016 23:55    1   0.002822919
    19-12-2016 23:56    1   0.002822919
    19-12-2016 23:57    1   0.002822919
    19-12-2016 23:58    1   0.002822919
    19-12-2016 23:59    1   0.002822919
```

Unfortunately the code I am using for this is really long and I can't pinpoint exactly where I could amend this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generic solution to multiple days of data in a single frame might look something like this. Get the start and end date and then `reindex` the entire frame and fill in the missing values.

```
start = df.index.min().date() 
end = df.index.max().date() + pd.Timedelta(1, 'D')
df.reindex(pd.date_range(start, end, freq='T', closed='left')).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: are you kidding me dude, this is my solution

Comment: I find this alternative answer useful as it presents the option to provide an end date for the timeseries extension as opposed to number of periods.

Answer (score 6):

you can:

`reindex` your data as

```
idx = pd.date_range('2016-12-19', periods=1440, freq='T')
df = df.reindex(idx)
```

and then forward fill any missing values using `df.mycol.ffill()`

Comment: This shouldn't work as it won't extend the time any further than the last time in the dataframe.