# Pandas create new date rows and forward fill column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id     date       value
 1  12/01/2016      5 
 1  25/02/2016      7 
 1  10/03/2017      13 
 2  02/04/2016      0 
 2  06/07/2016      1 
 2  18/04/2017      6
```

For each id there is a start date with a value and every few months there is another row with a date and a value.
I'd like to create a timeseries of each id. So I'd like to insert new rows with the next day (until today), where the value will be forward filled from the previous row.

So the dataframe becomes:

```
id     date       value
 1  12/01/2016      5 
 1  13/01/2016      5 
 1  14/01/2016      5 
 1  15/01/2016      5
 ...
 1  20/04/2017      13 
 ...
 2  18/04/2017      6 
 2  19/04/2017      6 
 2  20/04/2017      6
```

Eg answer to a similar question: [Appending datetime rows and forward filling data in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591801/appending-datetime-rows-and-forward-filling-data-in-pandas-dataframe)

But my dataframe isn't datetime indexed.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Does each group start with that groups earliest date?

Comment: @piRSquared Yes that's correct. For each 'id' the date needs to start from that groups earliest date until today()

Answer (score 8):

Consider a `groupby` and `merge` approach:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from datetime import date

txt= """
id     date       value
 1  12/01/2016      5 
 1  25/02/2016      7 
 1  10/03/2017      13 
 2  02/04/2016      0 
 2  06/07/2016      1 
 2  18/04/2017      6 
"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+", parse_dates=[1], dayfirst=True)

def expand_dates(ser):
    return pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(ser['date'].min(), date.today(), freq='D')})

newdf = df.groupby(['id']).apply(expand_dates).reset_index()\
          .merge(df, how='left')[['id', 'date', 'value']].ffill()
```

Comment: I have a similar question but I am not sure how to tweak your code for my case, could you please help me with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58313391/valueerror-cannot-reindex-a-non-unique-index-with-a-method-or-limit Thanks

Comment: Hi @Parfait, thank you for the solution. Can I ask you why when I choose `date.max()`  I cannot get all dates, it shows only a few days

Answer (score 3):

- create an index of dates from the earliest date in each group to today
- `reindex` with these dates and a fill method of `ffill`

---

```
today = pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.today()).floor('D')

def f(df):
    dates = pd.date_range(df.date.min(), today, name='date')
    d = df.set_index('date').sort_index().reindex(dates, method='ffill')
    return d.reset_index().reindex_axis(df.columns, 1)

df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(f)
```

---

```
     id       date  value
0     1 2016-01-12      5
1     1 2016-01-13      5
2     1 2016-01-14      5
3     1 2016-01-15      5
4     1 2016-01-16      5
5     1 2016-01-17      5
6     1 2016-01-18      5
7     1 2016-01-19      5
8     1 2016-01-20      5
9     1 2016-01-21      5
10    1 2016-01-22      5
11    1 2016-01-23      5
12    1 2016-01-24      5
13    1 2016-01-25      5
14    1 2016-01-26      5
15    1 2016-01-27      5
16    1 2016-01-28      5
17    1 2016-01-29      5
18    1 2016-01-30      5
19    1 2016-01-31      5
20    1 2016-02-01      5
21    1 2016-02-02      5
22    1 2016-02-03      5
23    1 2016-02-04      5
24    1 2016-02-05      5
25    1 2016-02-06      5
26    1 2016-02-07      5
27    1 2016-02-08      5
28    1 2016-02-09      5
29    1 2016-02-10      5
..   ..        ...    ...
354   2 2017-03-22      1
355   2 2017-03-23      1
356   2 2017-03-24      1
357   2 2017-03-25      1
358   2 2017-03-26      1
359   2 2017-03-27      1
360   2 2017-03-28      1
361   2 2017-03-29      1
362   2 2017-03-30      1
363   2 2017-03-31      1
364   2 2017-04-01      1
365   2 2017-04-02      1
366   2 2017-04-03      1
367   2 2017-04-04      1
368   2 2017-04-05      1
369   2 2017-04-06      1
370   2 2017-04-07      1
371   2 2017-04-08      1
372   2 2017-04-09      1
373   2 2017-04-10      1
374   2 2017-04-11      1
375   2 2017-04-12      1
376   2 2017-04-13      1
377   2 2017-04-14      1
378   2 2017-04-15      1
379   2 2017-04-16      1
380   2 2017-04-17      1
381   2 2017-04-18      6
382   2 2017-04-19      6
383   2 2017-04-20      6
```