# Add random data between rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've got a pandas dataframe like this. This contains a `timestamp`, `id`, `foo` and `bar`.
The `timestamp` data is around every 10 minutes.

```
timestamp            id  foo  bar
2019-04-14 00:00:10  1   0.10 0.05
2019-04-14 00:10:02  1   0.30 0.10
2019-04-14 00:00:00  2   0.10 0.05
2019-04-14 00:10:00  2   0.30 0.10
```

For each `id`, I'd like to create `5` additional `rows` with `timestamp` split equally between successive `rows`, and `foo` & `bar` values containing `random` values between the successive `rows`.

The start time should be the earliest `timestamp` for each `id` and the end time should be the latest `timestamp` for each `id`

So the output would be like this.

```
timestamp            id  foo  bar
2019-04-14 00:00:10  1   0.10 0.05
2019-04-14 00:02:10  1   0.14 0.06
2019-04-14 00:04:10  1   0.11 0.06
2019-04-14 00:06:10  1   0.29 0.07
2019-04-14 00:08:10  1   0.22 0.09
2019-04-14 00:10:02  1   0.30 0.10
2019-04-14 00:00:00  2   0.80 0.50
2019-04-14 00:02:00  2   0.45 0.48
2019-04-14 00:04:00  2   0.52 0.42
2019-04-14 00:06:00  2   0.74 0.48
2019-04-14 00:08:00  2   0.41 0.45
2019-04-14 00:10:00  2   0.40 0.40
```

I can reindex the `timestamp` column and create additional `timestamp` rows (eg. [Pandas create new date rows and forward fill column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526973/pandas-create-new-date-rows-and-forward-fill-column-values)).

But I can't seem to wrap my head around how to compute the random values for `foo` and `bar` between the successive rows.

Appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

The close, what you need is use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by first and last value of `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

df = (df.set_index('timestamp')
        .groupby('id')['foo','bar']
        .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index[0], x.index[-1], periods=6))))
```

Then create helper DataFrame with same size like original and [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) missing values:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(*df.shape), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
df = df.fillna(df1)
print (df)
                                 foo       bar
id                                            
1  2019-04-14 00:00:10.000  0.100000  0.050000
   2019-04-14 00:02:08.400  0.903435  0.755841
   2019-04-14 00:04:06.800  0.956002  0.253878
   2019-04-14 00:06:05.200  0.388454  0.257639
   2019-04-14 00:08:03.600  0.225535  0.195306
   2019-04-14 00:10:02.000  0.300000  0.100000
2  2019-04-14 00:00:00.000  0.100000  0.050000
   2019-04-14 00:02:00.000  0.180865  0.327581
   2019-04-14 00:04:00.000  0.417956  0.414400
   2019-04-14 00:06:00.000  0.012686  0.800948
   2019-04-14 00:08:00.000  0.716216  0.941396
   2019-04-14 00:10:00.000  0.300000  0.100000
```

Answer (score 1):

If the 'randomness' is not as crucial. We can use [`Series.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) which will keep the values between your `min` and `max` per group:

```
df_new = pd.concat([
    d.reindex(pd.date_range(d.timestamp.min(), d.timestamp.max(), periods=6))
    for _, d in df.groupby('id')
])
df_new['timestamp'] = df_new.index
df_new.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df_new = df_new[['timestamp']].merge(df, on='timestamp', how='left')
df_new['id'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

df_new[['foo', 'bar']] = df_new[['foo', 'bar']].apply(lambda x: x.interpolate())
```

---

Which gives the following output:

```
print(df_new)
                 timestamp   id   foo   bar
0  2019-04-14 00:00:10.000  1.0  0.10  0.05
1  2019-04-14 00:02:08.400  1.0  0.14  0.06
2  2019-04-14 00:04:06.800  1.0  0.18  0.07
3  2019-04-14 00:06:05.200  1.0  0.22  0.08
4  2019-04-14 00:08:03.600  1.0  0.26  0.09
5  2019-04-14 00:10:02.000  1.0  0.30  0.10
6  2019-04-14 00:00:00.000  2.0  0.10  0.05
7  2019-04-14 00:02:00.000  2.0  0.14  0.06
8  2019-04-14 00:04:00.000  2.0  0.18  0.07
9  2019-04-14 00:06:00.000  2.0  0.22  0.08
10 2019-04-14 00:08:00.000  2.0  0.26  0.09
11 2019-04-14 00:10:00.000  2.0  0.30  0.10
```

Comment: Hey @erfan thanks for this! the `randomness` isn't crucial. However, the `min` and `max` values should be based on successive rows. Whereas your solution provides random data based on min and max of the whole group.