# Create a new date column in pandas that has a range of dates for every row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that consists of unique `item_id`s as the following:

```
    item_id
0   123467
1   456789
2   546543
3   876641
```

I want to generate a date column in the dataframe, that would contain dates from 1st january,2021 to 30th december,2021 for each unique rows.
I want to have something like this:

```
    item_id  date
0   123467   2021-01-01
1   123467   2021-01-02
2   123467   2021-01-03
3   123467   2021-01-04
...
```

Can you suggest me a way to get this working?

Comment: Check out this one it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526973/pandas-create-new-date-rows-and-forward-fill-column-values

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.date_range('1/1/2021', periods = 365, freq ='d')
 
print(data)
```

you can append the output of this to your dataframe as new column